# undefined object in retrieving data aspnetcore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm having trouble in binding the records from json to my
    script in my view but I'm getting data from console.log. Can you
    please help me what am I missing? here's my code...

```
public JsonResult GetListOfQuestions()
        {
            List<Question> QuesList = _context.Question.ToList();
            return Json(QuesList);
        }


<div id="SetQuestionsList">
        <div id="LoadingStatus">

        </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script>
    $("#LoadingStatus").html("Loading....");
    $.get("/Questions/GetListOfQuestions", null, DataBind);
    function DataBind(QuesList) {
        var SetData = $("#SetQuestionsList");
        console.log(QuesList);
        for (var i = 0; i < QuesList.length; i++) {
            var aa = i + 1
            var Data =
                "<div class='row_{" + QuesList.QuestionId + "}'>" +
                    "<div class='panel panel-primary'>" +
                        "<div class='panel-heading'>" +
                            "<div class='row'>" +
                                "<div class='col-lg-10'>" +
                                    "<p>Question " + aa + "</p>" +
                                "</div>" +
                                "<div class='col-lg-1'>" +
                                    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='EditQuestion({" + QuesList.QuestionId + "})'>" +
                                        "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>Update" +
                                    "</a>" +
                                "</div>" +
                                "<div class='col-lg-1'>" +
                                    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteQuestionRecord({" + QuesList.QuestionId + "})'>" +
                                        "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>Delete" +
                                    "</a>" +
                                "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +

                        "<div class='panel-body'>" +
                            "<div class='row'>" +
                                "<div class='col-lg-12'>" +
                                    "<div class='form-group'>" +
                                        "<b>Description</b><br />" +
                                        "<p>" + QuesList.QuestionText + "</p>" +
                                    "</div>" +
                                "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</div>";
            SetData.append(Data);
            $("#LoadingStatus").html(" ");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked in the browser dev console, any feedback from the call? What have you done to debug?

Comment: off topic but what are you using for your views? there are many options available so you can template your views

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you created a jsfiddle or something similar so the community can help you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a version of jQuery >= 1.5, the following should help you determine what's going on. The way the script is currently written, using the ajax shorthand version, if there is an error in the call, jquery will fail silently. This way, you have an option to handle an error during the call execution and view the error in the browser dev console to help you debug the issue.

**Update** I added a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/willtx/xpvt214o/609478/) for you to understand it better in case the explanation isn't enough (you should provide a jsfiddle in the future)

Also, see the following json, I'm assuming your data is similar to https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fryq4. You have to take into account the data structure that is being converted into json from the backend.

```
  function getQuestions(){
     $("#LoadingStatus").show();

     $.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fryq4")
       .done(function( data ) {
        //call you binding function
        DataBind(data);
        })
       .fail( function(err){
         //handle the error in the UI, alert the user something went wrong, recover form the error
         alert("GetListOfQuestions error!");
         //chrome: display object in js console
         console.dir(err);
        })
       .always(function() {
         //hide loading spinner
         $("#LoadingStatus").hide();
       });
  }
```

#### Databind js function (shortened, see jsfiddle)

```
  function DataBind(QuesList) {
     var aa = 0;
     var QuestionList = $("#SetQuestionsList");

     //if you need to convert json to a js object use the builtin parser
     //Example: var data = JSON.parse(QuesList);

     //TODO good practice to check if valid list before trying to iterate the array

    //pay attention to your incoming object
    QuesList.questions.forEach(function(item){
         aa++;
         var question =
            "<div class='row_{" + item.questionId + "}'>" +
            "<div class='panel panel-primary'>" +
            "<div class='panel-heading'>" +
           "<div class='row'>" +
            "<div class='col-lg-10'>" +
           "<p>Question " + aa + "</p>" +
           "</div>" +
           "<div class='col-lg-1'>" +
           "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='EditQuestion({" + item.questionId + "})'>" +
           "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>Update" +
           "</a>" +
           "</div>" +
          "<div class='col-lg-1'>" +
          "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteQuestionRecord({" + item.questionId + "})'>" +
          "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>Delete" +
          "</a>" +
         "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
         "</div>" +
        ...
        "<b>Description</b><br />" +
         "<p>" + item.questionDescription + "</p>" +
         "</div>" +
         ...
         "</div>";

         QuestionList.append(question);
      });
  }
```

Comment: It's just that the returned data from json isn't binding properly.. in my console.log, i can see my records but it won't bind to my view and shows undefined.. Sorry if I wasn't helpful in your questions because I'm new in this. Please help me

(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
{questionId: "54e26f6f-16db-4702-24b3-08d5f6ceae08", questionTypeId: "4e0698de-adee-4d8e-bd6c-a6fc1a7ffae8", questionDescription: "Are you a curious and logical person who likes dis…u can learn by reading, study or problem solving?", quizId: "a8a7013f-3636-4cc2-a384-e0d8d5240b3a", questionTypeName: "Yes or No", …}

Comment: @amaurosis I updated the answer to include a jsfiddle in the event it still doesn't make sense. Your error is not mapping the data correctly. I hope it helps you

Comment: Hi Will, thank you so much for your help.. No errors now but it doesn't show anything.. even the console.log() is not showing, please see the code below if I missed something.

Comment: @amaurosis it sounds like you have a) a data mapping issue or b) you dom manipulation is off. Use the jsfiddle as a working ground so I can have insight into your issues. I can't help much from the postings here. The jsfiddle demonstrates getting a json response and displaying it. You'll need to modify the jsfiddle to mimic and duplicate the issues you're having so the community can help you. Let me know when you update the jsfiddle to do that and I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getQuestions() {
            $("#LoadingStatus").show();

            $.get("/Questions/GetListOfQuestions")
                .done(function (data) {
                    //call you binding function
                    console.log(data)
                    DataBind(data);
                })
                .fail(function (err) {
                    //handle the error in the UI, alert the user something went wrong, recover form the error
                    alert("GetListOfQuestions error!");
                    //chrome: display object in js console
                    console.dir(err);
                })
                .always(function () {
                    //hide loading spinner
                    $("#LoadingStatus").hide();
                });
        }

        function DataBind(QuesList) {
            var aa = 0;
            var QuestionList = $("#SetQuestionsList");
            console.log(QuesList);
            //if you need to convert json to a js object use the builtin parser
            //Example: var data = JSON.parse(QuesList);

            //TODO good practice to check if valid list before trying to iterate the array

            //pay attention to your incoming object
            QuesList.questions.forEach(function (item) {
                aa++;
                var question =
                    "<div class='row_{" + item.QuestionId + "}'>" +
                    "<div class='panel panel-primary'>" +
                    "<div class='panel-heading'>" +
                    "<div class='row'>" +
                    "<div class='col-lg-10'>" +
                    "<p>Question " + aa + "</p>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='col-lg-1'>" +
                    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='EditQuestion({" + item.QuestionId + "})'>" +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>Update" +
                    "</a>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='col-lg-1'>" +
                    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteQuestionRecord({" + item.QuestionId + "})'>" +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>Delete" +
                    "</a>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='panel-body'>" +
                    "<div class='row'>" +
                    "<div class='col-md-6'>" +
                    "<div class='form-group'>" +
                    "<b>Question Type</b><br />" +
                    "<text>" + item.QuestionTypeName + "</text>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='row'>" +
                    "<div class='col-lg-12'>" +
                    "<div class='form-group'>" +
                    "<b>Description</b><br />" +
                    "<p>" + item.QuestionDescription + "</p>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>";

                QuestionList.append(question);
            });
        }
</script>
```